# Javascript Modularized Promise Chain Out of Order

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to figure out the reason why my promise chain is executing out of order despite writing a non-nested then chain. My functions have been modularized to reduce the code bloat that will happen in my chain (I expect to have five then methods) and I'm not sure if something within those modules are causing the jump in the order or if it is due to my overall promise structure.

**Here is the terminal output:**

```
Executing (a6bf615e-5497-47b2-8aea-3f7d70927cba): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (a6bf615e-5497-47b2-8aea-3f7d70927cba): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Step 1: Document Find
Step 3: Cancel Stripe Subscription
string //console.log(typeof subscriptionId);
sub_jsdfjsdfjdsfjsdfj //console.log(subscriptionId)
Executing (a6bf615e-5497-47b2-8aea-3f7d70927cba): SELECT ....
Step 2: Set Array
[ 13, 14 ] //console.log(documentArr);
undefined //console.log(canceledStripeAccount);
undefined //console.log(canceledAt)
```

**Here is my promise structure:**

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var models = require('../../../models/db-index');
var deleteAccount = require('./delete-account');


//DELETE /settings/account
exports.delete = function(req, res){
    var documents;
    var documentArr;
    var canceledStripeAccount;
    var canceledAt;

    return models.sequelize.transaction().then(function(t){

        return deleteAccount.queryAllDocuments(req.session.organizationId, t)
        .then(function(_document){
                console.log("Step 2: Set Array");
                documentArr = _document;
                console.log(documentArr);
        })
        .then(deleteAccount.cancelStripeAccount(req.session.subscriptionId, canceledStripeAccount, canceledAt))
        .then(function(canceledStripeAccount){
            console.log(canceledStripeAccount);
            console.log(canceledAt)
        });
    });
};
```

**Modules File:**

```
var models = require('../../../models/db-index');
var components = require('./components');
var stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);

module.exports = {

    queryAllDocuments: function(organization, t){
        console.log("Step 1: Document Find");
        return models.Document.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                include: [{
                    model: models.Organization,
                    where: {
                        organizationId: organization
                    }
                }]
            }],
            transaction: t
        })
    },

    cancelStripeAccount: function(subscriptionId, canceledStripeAccount, canceledAt){
        console.log("Step 3: Cancel Stripe Subscription");
        console.log(typeof subscriptionId);
        console.log(subscriptionId)
        return stripe.subscriptions.del(subscriptionId).then(function(_canceledStripeAccount){
            return canceledStripeAccount = _canceledStripeAccount;
            //canceledAt = canceledStripeAccount.canceled_at;
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but `components` is not defined in your `then` handler

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I actually removed that function to clean up the code for the question. Unrelated to the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function directly before `.then()` even calls its callback (and passing the return value from that to `.then()`):

```
.then(deleteAccount.cancelStripeAccount(req.session.subscriptionId, 
        canceledStripeAccount, canceledAt))
```

Instead, `.then()` should be passed a function reference so it can call the function sometime later:

```
.then(() => deleteAccount.cancelStripeAccount(req.session.subscriptionId,
              canceledStripeAccount, canceledAt))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and am I correct in saying that the previous `then()` function has no place to return the callback object before `deleteAccount` is called, which is why it jumps the order? I'm also sorry that I'm not well versed in es6 at the moment, so would the es5 equivalent be a `function(obj){}` before `deleteAccount`? `.then(function(){},deleteAccount...)`?